# How to fix "11200 HTTP retrieval failure error" in Twilio Programmable SMS(WhatsApp)

Tags: python, http, webserver, twilio, dialogflow-es

I want to understand what gives rise to the 11200 HTTP retrieval error? I've sent the response to the POST request to DialogFlow, shouldn't it be handling sending this response to Twilio?

## Here's what I've done until now

I've setup a local python server, and exposed the localhost using a ngrok. The idea is to create a weather bot using Twilio Programmable SMS. The initial message to Twilio is forwarded to DialogFlow, which then sends a post request to my python server. I then process this request, and get the relevant weather information from OpenWeatherMap API. Being relatively new to server dev, I assume I then need to send a response with the right structure as mentioned in the DialogFlow guidelines (include fulfillmentText parameter for eg.) back to DialogFlow, which then should send the response to Twilio and that should show up on my WhatsApp Twilio Sandbox.
** But what I get is a 11200 HTTP retrieval failure error in the Twilio Degugger, I wanted to understand if I'm sending the Data to DialogFlow correctly and what gives rise to this error** I read the documentation for the error on Twilio's website but that didn't help me much in understanding the problem in my case.

I had tried the same program using a PHP server, and it worked perfectly fine. I just wanted to recreate the program using a Python server, since I'm more comfortable using it for the time being.

// DO post method of webhook.py

```
def do_POST(self):
    try:
        content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)

        requestjson = json.loads(post_body)
        city = requestjson["queryResult"]["parameters"]["geo-city"]
        if city:
            print(city)
            info = getWeatherInformation(city)
            print(info) # Prints temp in city and weather condition successfully
            self.send_response(200)
            self.wfile.write(info.encode(encoding = "utf_8"))
```

#### info variable is returned in the following manner from getWeatherInformation

```
res = {"fulfillmentText":response}
info = json.dumps(res)
return info
```

#### Console debug statements for city Melbourne

```
Web Server running on port: 8080
Melbourne
{"fulfillmentText": "It is 31.29 degrees with clear sky"}
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2019 23:00:34] "POST /webhook.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

#### PHP Webhook code from a blog post that works correctly

/
* Part of the code that sends weather data response to Dialogflow
*/

```
function sendFulfillmentResponse($temperature, $weatherDescription)
{
   $response = "It is $temperature degrees with $weatherDescription";

   $fulfillment = array(
       "fulfillmentText" => $response
   );

   echo(json_encode($fulfillment));
}
```

I expect to see a response from the Twilio Sandbox account on WhatsApp, similar to when I created the server using PHP. Instead I get the 11200 error in Twilio Debugger, but no errors in the Server Terminal.

Comment: Is there more information about the error in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger)? You should be able to see the response the Dialogflow server returned to Twilio and what was wrong with it.

Comment: @philnash The debug message just read "Bad Request", but then I viewed it by Webhook URL, and got two categories, null and the ngrok public facing uri for my server, the error message for the public uri was "Bad Request", but for the null category was(I guess expectedly): "The URI scheme, of the URI null, must be equal (ignoring case) to 'http', 'https', 'ws', or 'wss'". Does that help answer your query?

Comment: The `null` version comes from the fallback URL which is currently unsupported with the WhatsApp API. So, digging into the Bad Request error, can you see the actual request and response that was made?

Comment: Yes. The Request was as follows: URL-> https://bots.dialogflow.com/twilio/... . Parameters-> Body: "What's the weather in Melbourne", SmsStatus: "received"  along with other IDs. Message Text-> Msg:"Bad Request", sourceComponent: "14100", ErrorCode: "11200", httpResponse: "400". The Response Body was: Empty Speech. Does this mean the problem was with the Request itself? @philnash

Comment: Looks like DialogFlow isn't responding correctly to the Twilio request then. Are there any logs inside DialogFlow that could shed some light on this?

Comment: Ah yes, looking at the history of requests on DialogFlow it says, "Webhook call failed. Check response JSON for error details". If by response JSON they mean the , response the python server sends, its contents are only, "{"fullfillmentText": "It is 31.29 degrees with clear sky"}"

Comment: Did the Python server definitely send that back? Did it definitely get a City to search with? Did the Weather API succeed as expected? What's the timeout on a DialogFlow fulfillment request? I've not worked with a combination of Python and DialogFlow before, just trying to ask questions that might lead us somewhere.

Comment: The things I'm absolutely sure of are: 1) Yes, I got the city extracted from my WhatsApp message and sent to me via a DialogFlow post request.2) The weather API worked as expected and gave me temp and climate condition. 3) The timeout on fulfillment requests is 5 seconds. The only part I am doubtful of is whether I'm actually sending the response correctly. The format for the Post request from Dialog flow and the expected format of my response can be found here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works. I'm almost certain it has something to do with my Python server.

Comment: The key line in the code that is supposed to accomplish sending the response is: self.wfile.write(info.encode(encoding = "utf_8")).

Comment: What does the ngrok dashboard (http://127.0.0.1:4040 when ngrok is running) say your response to the fulfillment webhook is?

Comment: There are only Requests displayed, in the format: {
    "responseId": "5c648"....,
    "queryResult": {
        "queryText": "What's the weather in Melbourne",
        "parameters": {
            "geo-city": "Melbourne"
        },
        "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
        "fulfillmentMessages": .... This almost makes it certain, that I'm not sending the response properly(if sending anything at all) from my server.

Comment: Seems that way. Looks like you are doing it in a very hands on way. Have you considered a small framework like Flask to receive requests and build responses?

Comment: "in a very hands on way." Haha, My sentiments precisely :D! Yes, I've been looking at alternatives, and Flask was the first one to pop-up. I'll definitely give it a try and probably end up writing a Medium post about it, would make sure to tag you, when I'm done(only if you're interested i.e). Hopefully Flask should make things straight-forward. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: I would reckon it would make this a bit easier, and likely give you some decent logging to discover if you've done something wrong. Good luck with it, and I'd love to read about this once you've got it sorted.

Comment: @philnash I used Flask, and everything worked swimmingly :), thank you for you suggestion . Also I realized there was a typo in my return json in the earlier program(fullfillment -> fulfillment), but changing that still didn't help wrt sending the response to the post request. But hey I started learning a new framework out of this, so very thankful (y).

Comment: Brilliant, glad it's working for you now! And working with Flask will definitely make you happier than handling web requests by hand!